# Laravel Multi-Application Routing

Tags: php, git, laravel

I'm working on a platform which runs multiple Laravel applications that interact via a single database.

Each Laravel instance is responsable for it's own logic, i.e:

- Admin module (own subdomain)
- User module (own subdomain)
- Homepage module (own domain)
- Saas-ish module (different domains)

Now the problem im facing with routing is the following:

`I want to be able to create/generate URL's for the other modules in my platform and for each of the domains inside the Saas-ish module`

**Things i've thought about**

**Option 1**

Make routes a shared folder/file (via git submodules or a package) and generate the route file based on the Saas domains and subdomains with the `domain` group option (and cache it). While this is a viable option, I'd prefer not to load a massive file with all the routes, when all I need is 1 or 2 per request.

**Option 2**

All routes in the DB. Make a RouteGenerator which will handle this for me. However I'm thorn in this option, because I think it the domains in the Saas module, (which are basicaly entities in my DB) and the other module's subdomains (which arn't entities in my database) are too different. So this may not be the best option.

One of these might be the solution for my problem, and i'm just not seeing it, OR it's something completely else.

Please share your insight...

Answer (score -3):

**No. Just no.**

Here is your option: Merge.

This is more or less not optional. You never run the same framework multiple times for different parts of an app. It's a waste of space and awful to maintain.

You **MUST** merge your application into one.

Comment: The only non-optional thing for me was the merge. Each instance is an proper application on it's own. I just need to figure out some sort of awareness of the other routes for some cross linking when needed.

Comment: Why is it set up like that? It makes no sense if they all share a DB.